# Trouble with percentage

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I don't know if I'll be able to explain all the details of the data, but I'll try my best. Sorry in advance.

The problem is that the matrix has 4 levels. In the fourth level, percentage is not calculating correctly :

[image]

The four levels are from different tables:

"Categorias" is Ordenação[Ordenação DRE Gerencial]

"Agrupador Nível II" is ÍNDICE NÍVEL 2[Agrupador Nivel ll]

"Descrição" is Categorias[Descrição]
"Nome Fantansia" is "Cliente/Fornecedor/Transportadora"[Nome Fantansia]

The relationships :

[image]

This is the percentage measure:

```
RB%2 = divide([realizado_correto_categoria],'@Medidas'[Medida KPIS],0)
```

This is the measures mentioned:

Measure 1:

```
realizado_correto_categoria = 
VAR vArsubtotal = SELECTEDVALUE('ORDENAÇÃO'[Calculado])
RETURN
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    vArsubtotal = 0, [Realizado_categorias],
    vArsubtotal <> 0 && NOT(ISINSCOPE('INDICE NÍVEL 2'[Agrupador Nível II])), [Realizado_categorias],
    BLANK()
)
```

The next:

```
Realizado_categorias = var Subtotal = SELECTEDVALUE('ORDENAÇÃO'[Calculado])
    var ordemContexto = Max('ORDENAÇÃO'[Índice])
    var ValorSubtotalresumo = 
    CALCULATE(SUM(Movimentos_unificado[VALOR_USAR]),Filter(ALLNOBLANKROW('ORDENAÇÃO'), 'ORDENAÇÃO'[Índice] <= ordemContexto))
    Return
    SWITCH(
        True(),
        Subtotal = 0, SUM(Movimentos_unificado[VALOR_USAR]),
        Subtotal = 1 && NOT(ISINSCOPE('INDICE NÍVEL 2'[Agrupador Nível II])), ValorSubtotalresumo,
        BLANK()
    )
```

Measure 2:

```
Medida KPIS = CALCULATE([Realizado_categorias], Filter(ALL(DE_PARA_CTB),(DE_PARA_CTB[Código Nível II]= "1.1")))
```

If it's anything confusing, I can try to explain in more detail. I tried to screenshot the data model, but it looks a mess.

Thanks in advance!

I've tried to change relationships and filter tables, but it didn't work. I just want the fourth level from matrix stops to calculate the percentage considering the value of the row as 100%